# Rename a HTML file based on the content of a tag

Tags: files, rename, html

I have a lot of html files that I want to rename according to the content of 
the tag h1.

Any suggestion on how to do it on bash?

Example of a file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="pt-BR"><head><meta charset="utf-8"><title>Repositório - MAIS</title>
 <script src="lib/tudo.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="cabecalho"></div>
<div id="corpo">
<h1>teste</h1>

<div class="Experimento"></div>
<div class="gallery">
<img class="image-gallery" src="img/2dados.png">
</div>

<br><br><strong>Mídia:</strong> experimento (uma aula dupla)

<br><br><strong>Descrição:</strong> este experimento propõe 4 jogos diferentes, todos baseados no lançamento de 2 dados comuns. Discutindo as chances de cada jogador vencer cada um dos jogos, os estudantes terão a chance de discutir vários conteúdos relacionados à probabilidade

<br><br><strong>Conteúdo:</strong> experimento aleatório, espaço amostral, eventos equiprováveis, probabilidade

<br><br><strong>Recomendação de uso:</strong> este experimento pode ser usado como introdução ou aplicação dos conceitos iniciais de probabilidade.

<br><br><strong>Autoria:</strong> este experimento foi desenvolvido pela <a class="externo" href="http://www.mais.mat.br" target="_blank">Mais</a> e pode ser utuilziado e distribído livremente, contanto que citada a autoria original.

<a class="download" href="http://www.mais.mat.br/recursos/images/5/5b/2dados.pdf">Baixar</a>

</div>
<div id="rodape"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want the file renamed to "teste.html"

If it is helpful, this tag is always on the 8th line of each file and alone (nothing else on the same line). Also, there is always only one occurrence of h1 in each file.

Comment: I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, xmllint ...).

Comment: Please add sample input.

Comment: you should never rely on a line number when dealing with XML/HTML data. Post the crucial tag name and its content

Comment: Are you suggesting an edit your own post? Don't worry, the system is smart and the mods can merge your accounts. (Btw, using multiple accounts is allowed here, only misusing this is not (for example, upvoting your own post on your other account)).

Comment: @peterh I'm afraid mods can't merge accounts. Leo, please request a merge of your two accounts by following the instructions here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts

Comment: Uhm, sorry, mods know it better :-) So I suggest to make this merging. You will likely have to visit the [contact page](https://unix.stackexchange.com/contact).

Answer (score 3):

With [xmllint](/questions/tagged/xmllint) :

### File:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a>foo</a>
        <b>bar</b>
        <c>base</c>
    </body>
</html>
```

### Command:

```
for file in *.html; do
    tag=$(xmllint --xpath '//b/text()' $file)
    echo mv "$file" "${tag}_$file"
done
```

### Comment:

Put off the echo command when your tests become ok to run the command for real

Comment: maybe `echo mv "$file" "${tag}_$file"` - that way the quotes are still correct if `echo` is deleted from the line.   Also, why not put in a `<h1>...</h1>` example since that's what the OP wanted?    finally, a pipe to `head -n 1` would be useful in case there's more than one `h1` tag.

Answer (score 1):

The right way with **`find`** + **`xmlstarlet`** tools:

```
find . -type f -name "*.html" -exec sh -c \
'name=$(xmlstarlet sel -t -v "//tagname" $1 2>/dev/null); 
 [ ! -z "$name" ] && echo mv "$1" "${1%%/*}/${name}.html"' _ {} \;
```

- `name` - variable which is assigned with a value (the contents of the tag `tagname`) for the new filename
- `[ ! -z "$name" ]` - check if a new filename is not empty (i.e. `<tagname>` was found and it had a value)

Answer (score 1):

With xmlstarlet:

```
xmlstarlet format --html teste.html | xmlstarlet select --html --template --value-of '//html/body/div/h1'
```

Output:

```
teste
```

I used `xmlstarlet format --html teste.html` to fix your non valid html code.

Answer (score 0):

If tag is alone on the 8-th line, you have many way to pick it.

```
tag=$( awk NR==8 file )

tag=$( awk 'NR == 8 { print ;}' file )
```

where

- `NR` is number of record (line number)
- `print` is implied action

or

```
tag=$(sed -n 8p file)
```

where

- `-n` will not echo line
- `8p` print 8th line.

and many other.

as notted in comment, relaying on line number is risky. If file is a valid xml file, extracting tag would be easier and safest.

Answer (score 0):

My final solution was the code below, combining two suggestions. Thank you, guys!

```
for file in *.html; do
    tag=$(xmlstarlet format --html $file | xmlstarlet select --html --template --value-of '//html/body/div/h1')
    mv "$file" "${tag}.html"
done
```

It worked great for my files!